# Difference between なかなかに and なかなか

Tags: grammar

> この変わり身の速さと無節操っぷりは毎年のことであったが、改めて考えると興味深い現象のかもしれない。何しろ、つい先日まで諸人こぞりてきよしこの夜していた人々が、今やもういくつ寝るお正月状態なのである。お祭りごととなれば宗教国籍関係ない日本人ではあるけれど、ここまで大きなイベントが約一週間しか間を置かず連続するというのも、**なかなかに**慌ただしい話ではあった。師も走らねばならないはずである。

I have simple question. Since なかなか is already an adverb, why is there a に added to なかなか? Is there any difference between なかなかに and なかなか?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm sure they're related, both goo.ne and スーパー大辞林 treat [なかなかに](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%AD%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB/#:%7E:text=%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E2%80%90%E3%81%AB%E3%80%90%E4%B8%AD%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%80%91&text=%EF%BC%91%20%E4%B8%AD%E9%80%94%E5%8D%8A%E7%AB%AF%E3%81%AB%E3%80%82,%E3%81%AA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B%E3%80%82&text=%EF%BC%92%20%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%80%82,%E3%82%80%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D%E3%80%82) and [なかなか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%AD%E4%B8%AD/#jn-163231) as different words. Here is the definition of なかなかに pasted for convenience:

> １ 中途半端に。なまじっか。
> 「―君に恋ひずは比良の浦の海人 (あま) ならましを玉藻刈りつつ」〈万・二七四三〉
> **２ かえって。むしろ**。
> 「―死なば安けむ君が目を見ず久ならばすべなかるべし」〈万・三九三四〉

While なかなかに only has two definitions as a 副詞(adverb), なかなか has 3 definitions as a 形容動詞(na-adj) and 3 more as a 副詞(adverb).

In your sentence, it seems like なかなかに is being used as its second definition, meaning something along the lines of "rather", "actually" or "contrary to expectations".